# Eclipse show view wizard says Use f2 to display the description... but where to set the description for the view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse Window>Show View, in the bottom we can see a text saying "use f2 to display the description for a selected view" now if we select any view and press f2, it always show "no description available" .
Now I have created a View and that view is available in showView eclipse menu , but I want to set the description for the same.
So in ViewPart, where exactly I need to do the description setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=128529) bug report, the description is set in the `description` tag of the view in the `plugin.xml`.

An example:

```
<view
    name="Sample View"
    icon="icons/sample.gif"
    category="test"
    class="test.views.SampleView"
    id="test.views.SampleView">
    <description>A very long descriptive text.
                 With a new line comes still more.
                 And more ... and more.</description>
</view>
```

Result:

[image]